# Advanced Rails Active Record Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Calling Active Record query experts! I'm having problem debugging an N+1 query. Here's a summary of my models and the page that's causing the issue. **I'd love to find a good way to create a query for this page, and figure out the best way to cache this page.** Any help is much appreciated!!

```
class Brief < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :account
  has_one :user, through: :account
  has_many :submissions

class Account < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user, touch: true
  has_many :briefs
end

class Submission < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :brief, touch: true
  belongs_to :user
```

I have a page of @briefs where I'm looking to display for each brief:

- Brief account name -> brief.account.name
- Brief's submission status for the current_user -> brief.submissions.where(user: current_user).status ** Note this could return nil if a User has not created a Submission for a Brief

```
class BriefsController < BaseController
  def index
    @briefs = Brief.includes([:account, :submissions]).order(expiration_date: :desc).live
  end


class Brief < ApplicationRecord
 ### CLASS METHODS
 def self.live
    Brief.all.select { |brief| brief.active? == true }
  end
```

Currently this is how I'm caching the page:

**live_briefs.html.erb**

```
<% cache @briefs, expires_in: 1.hour do %> 
  <% @briefs.each do |brief| %>
    <% cache brief do %>
      <%= render 'live_briefs/components/brief', brief: brief %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**_.brief.html.erb**

```
<%= brief.account.name %>
<%= live_brief_submission_status(brief, current_user) %>
```

**brief_helper.rb (this is what's causing the added queries)**

```
def live_brief_submission_status(brief, user)
    submission = brief.submissions.where(user: user).first
    if submission.present?
      case submission.status
      when "approved"
        tag.div "Approved", class: "inline-flex items-center px-3 py-0.5 rounded-full text-sm font-medium leading-5 bg-indigo-100 text-indigo-800"
      when "invited"
        tag.div "Invited", class: "inline-flex items-center px-3 py-0.5 rounded-full text-sm font-medium leading-5 bg-green-400 text-white"
      when "pending"
        tag.div "Pending", class: "inline-flex items-center px-3 py-0.5 rounded-full text-sm font-medium leading-5 bg-gray-100 text-gray-800"
      when "declined"
        tag.div "Declined", class: "inline-flex items-center px-3 py-0.5 rounded-full text-sm font-medium leading-5 bg-red-100 text-red-800"
      else
      end
    else
      tag.div "Apply Now!", class: "inline-flex items-center pl-3 py-0.5 rounded-full text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-gray-800"
    end
  end
```

And this is the output when I load the page:

```
Started GET "/briefs/live" for ::1 at 2020-06-01 15:34:11 -0700
Processing by LiveBriefsController#index as HTML
  User Load (5.9ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Brief Load (10.8ms)  SELECT "briefs".* FROM "briefs" ORDER BY "briefs"."expiration_date" DESC
  ↳ app/models/brief.rb:32:in `live'
  Account Load (7.5ms)  SELECT "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."id" IN ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10)  [["id", 10], ["id", 4], ["id", 9], ["id", 3], ["id", 6], ["id", 5], ["id", 7], ["id", 2], ["id", 1], ["id", 8]]
  ↳ app/models/brief.rb:32:in `live'
  Submission Load (46.7ms)  SELECT "submissions".* FROM "submissions" WHERE "submissions"."brief_id" IN ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19, $20, $21, $22, $23, $24, $25, $26, $27, $28, $29, $30)  [["brief_id", 27], ["brief_id", 9], ["brief_id", 21], ["brief_id", 22], ["brief_id", 10], ["brief_id", 29], ["brief_id", 24], ["brief_id", 3], ["brief_id", 1], ["brief_id", 6], ["brief_id", 25], ["brief_id", 7], ["brief_id", 2], ["brief_id", 23], ["brief_id", 5], ["brief_id", 28], ["brief_id", 26], ["brief_id", 30], ["brief_id", 8], ["brief_id", 4], ["brief_id", 14], ["brief_id", 17], ["brief_id", 16], ["brief_id", 11], ["brief_id", 13], ["brief_id", 20], ["brief_id", 12], ["brief_id", 15], ["brief_id", 19], ["brief_id", 18]]
  ↳ app/models/brief.rb:32:in `live'
  Rendering layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering live_briefs/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered live_briefs/components/_title.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 55)
  Submission Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "submissions".* FROM "submissions" WHERE "submissions"."brief_id" = $1 AND "submissions"."user_id" = $2 ORDER BY "submissions"."id" ASC LIMIT $3  [["brief_id", 9], ["user_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/helpers/brief_helper.rb:20:in `live_brief_submission_status'
  Rendered live_briefs/components/_brief.html.erb (Duration: 32.0ms | Allocations: 3088)
  Submission Load (3.8ms)  SELECT "submissions".* FROM "submissions" WHERE "submissions"."brief_id" = $1 AND "submissions"."user_id" = $2 ORDER BY "submissions"."id" ASC LIMIT $3  [["brief_id", 10], ["user_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/helpers/brief_helper.rb:20:in `live_brief_submission_status'
  Rendered live_briefs/components/_brief.html.erb (Duration: 11.7ms | Allocations: 2119)
  Submission Load (27.0ms)  SELECT "submissions".* FROM "submissions" WHERE "submissions"."brief_id" = $1 AND "submissions"."user_id" = $2 ORDER BY "submissions"."id" ASC LIMIT $3  [["brief_id", 3], ["user_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/helpers/brief_helper.rb:20:in `live_brief_submission_status'
  Rendered live_briefs/components/_brief.html.erb (Duration: 49.2ms | Allocations: 2028)
  Submission Load (26.0ms)  SELECT "submissions".* FROM "submissions" WHERE "submissions"."brief_id" = $1 AND "submissions"."user_id" = $2 ORDER BY "submissions"."id" ASC LIMIT $3  [["brief_id", 1], ["user_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/helpers/brief_helper.rb:20:in `live_brief_submission_status'
  Rendered live_briefs/components/_brief.html.erb (Duration: 34.2ms | Allocations: 2034)
  Submission Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "submissions".* FROM "submissions" WHERE "submissions"."brief_id" = $1 AND "submissions"."user_id" = $2 ORDER BY "submissions"."id" ASC LIMIT $3  [["brief_id", 6], ["user_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/helpers/brief_helper.rb:20:in `live_brief_submission_status'
  Rendered live_briefs/components/_brief.html.erb (Duration: 8.2ms | Allocations: 2028)
  Submission Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "submissions".* FROM "submissions" WHERE "submissions"."brief_id" = $1 AND "submissions"."user_id" = $2 ORDER BY "submissions"."id" ASC LIMIT $3  [["brief_id", 7], ["user_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/helpers/brief_helper.rb:20:in `live_brief_submission_status'
  Rendered live_briefs/components/_brief.html.erb (Duration: 12.0ms | Allocations: 2028)
  Submission Load (12.5ms)  SELECT "submissions".* FROM "submissions" WHERE "submissions"."brief_id" = $1 AND "submissions"."user_id" = $2 ORDER BY "submissions"."id" ASC LIMIT $3  [["brief_id", 2], ["user_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/helpers/brief_helper.rb:20:in `live_brief_submission_status'
  Rendered live_briefs/components/_brief.html.erb (Duration: 18.2ms | Allocations: 2027)
  Submission Load (136.9ms)  SELECT "submissions".* FROM "submissions" WHERE "submissions"."brief_id" = $1 AND "submissions"."user_id" = $2 ORDER BY "submissions"."id" ASC LIMIT $3  [["brief_id", 5], ["user_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/helpers/brief_helper.rb:20:in `live_brief_submission_status'
  Rendered live_briefs/components/_brief.html.erb (Duration: 157.4ms | Allocations: 2405)
  Submission Load (168.4ms)  SELECT "submissions".* FROM "submissions" WHERE "submissions"."brief_id" = $1 AND "submissions"."user_id" = $2 ORDER BY "submissions"."id" ASC LIMIT $3  [["brief_id", 8], ["user_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/helpers/brief_helper.rb:20:in `live_brief_submission_status'
  Rendered live_briefs/components/_brief.html.erb (Duration: 177.6ms | Allocations: 2035)
  Submission Load (31.7ms)  SELECT "submissions".* FROM "submissions" WHERE "submissions"."brief_id" = $1 AND "submissions"."user_id" = $2 ORDER BY "submissions"."id" ASC LIMIT $3  [["brief_id", 4], ["user_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/helpers/brief_helper.rb:20:in `live_brief_submission_status'
  Rendered live_briefs/components/_brief.html.erb (Duration: 39.5ms | Allocations: 2029)
  Rendered live_briefs/index.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 581.8ms | Allocations: 23083)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
  Rendered layouts/_sidebar.html.erb (Duration: 9.3ms | Allocations: 1433)
  Rendered layouts/_notifications.html.erb (Duration: 1.8ms | Allocations: 86)
  Rendered application/_css_overrides.html.erb (Duration: 0.2ms | Allocations: 56)
  Rendered layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 631.4ms | Allocations: 28281)
Completed 200 OK in 994ms (Views: 227.1ms | ActiveRecord: 484.8ms | Allocations: 93326)
```

Comment: you can start by turning `self.live` into a proper scope or method, like `Brief.where(active: true)`, because you're querying the whole table every time you call that method (i'm assuming that `active` is a column in `briefs` table

Comment: @mr_sudaca calling `Brief.where` is just as bad as it won't actually chain like a scope is supposed to and will just return a new relation with just that condition. You want to call the method on self in a scope so that it is chainable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure the method is chainable by calling it on self so that you can add it to an existing relation:

```
class Brief < ApplicationRecord
  def self.live
   where(active: true)
  end
end
```

Then make sure you eager load the needed data in the controller:

```
@briefs = Brief.live
               .eager_load(submissions: :user)
               .order(expiration_date: :desc)
```

Instead of using `.where` which will always create a query use the methods from enumerable to traverse the association which is loaded in memory:

```
def live_brief_submission_status(brief, user)
  submission = brief.submissions.detect {|s| s.user = user }
  if submission.present?
    case submission.status
    when "approved"
      tag.div "Approved", class: "inline-flex items-center px-3 py-0.5 rounded-full text-sm font-medium leading-5 bg-indigo-100 text-indigo-800"
    when "invited"
      tag.div "Invited", class: "inline-flex items-center px-3 py-0.5 rounded-full text-sm font-medium leading-5 bg-green-400 text-white"
    when "pending"
      tag.div "Pending", class: "inline-flex items-center px-3 py-0.5 rounded-full text-sm font-medium leading-5 bg-gray-100 text-gray-800"
    when "declined"
      tag.div "Declined", class: "inline-flex items-center px-3 py-0.5 rounded-full text-sm font-medium leading-5 bg-red-100 text-red-800"
    end
  else
    tag.div "Apply Now!", class: "inline-flex items-center pl-3 py-0.5 rounded-full text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-gray-800"
  end
end
```

But that query should really be refactored out of the helper method to reduce its cyclic complexity and redestribute the responsibilites.

Comment: Thank you. This is truly fantastic. I changed 

```@briefs = Brief.live
               .eager_load(submissions: :user)
               .order(expiration_date: :desc)```
 to 
```@briefs = Brief
               .eager_load(submissions: :user)
               .order(expiration_date: :desc)
               .live 
``` 

               The result is now 1 large SQL query instead of 14. Thanks!!

Comment: The order does not really matter since they are chainable methods.